# Looking for a primitive ...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is to find $f$ such that
$$f^{\prime}(x)+\int_0^x f(t)\times u(t)dt=0$$ where $u$ is given.

I tried to find a primitive of the function $\frac{f^{\prime\prime}}{f}$ but I think it is not an easy way.

Is there any suggestion how to solve this ?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (essentially) trying to solve the differential equation $y''+uy=0$.

While this is a homogeneous linear second order differential equation, it cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions even for some very nice, very reasonable choices of $u$.

For example: If you choose $u=-x$, then the solutions of $y''-xy=0$ are called [Airy functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function). These functions aren't elementary.

So in the end, trying to solve this equation for a "general" $u$ is more or less hopeless!

Comment: In fact this problem is obtained by some developments of the original one which is a differential system: $$\varphy^{\prime}=u_1\times \psi, \quad \psi^{\prime}=u_2\times \varphy$. But this one led me to a Riccati equation which took me to the problem above :-(

Comment: It's just too general of a system to have a nice, clean closed form solution. Oh well.